# Jrebel remote server configuration error: “IllegalStateException: Unable to determine code source archive from file...”

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jrebel

When I added "-Drebel.remoting_plugin=true" to run my Spring Boot jar file, I got this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine code source archive from file.[image]

Tips:
[Jrebel remote server configuration](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/remoteserver/serverconfiguration.html)

Comment: This seems to be a bug introduced since JRebel 7.0.13. Will let you know once it's fixed.

Comment: If possible, update spring-boot to 1.4 or later, this error only happens on prior versions.

Comment: Yes, this bug has been fixed in Jrebel 7.1.5

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in JRebel versions 7.0.13-7.1.4 which caused the ProtectionDomain CodeSource location URL to be incorrect for reloadable classes that are originally loaded from a JAR.

This affects spring-boot versions <= 1.3.8 as the bootstrap classes and application classes were not separated in the fat jar(1.4.0 introduced `BOOT-INF/classes`), so a spring-boot internal class was reloadable and received the incorrect URL.

Until 7.1.5 is released you can download the nightly build here: https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/nightly-build/

Comment: Thanks so much for your help